# Views Contextual Filter by Day and Night

Tags: views, datetime

I have a content type with a boolean field, using radio buttons for day and night.

I would like to create a view with a contextual filter, which shows "day content" between 8:00 am - 8:00 pm and "night content" between 8:00 pm and 8:00 am.

Which is the best way for creating the contextual filter or view?

Or if you'd have a better suggestion, I could change my content type and fields too.

Answer (score 2):

your approach is correct.

You can do one thing..Just create a view and contextual filter in view for radio field.
use hook_views_pre_view() hook to add arguments.

```
function MODULE_NAME_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if ($view->name == 'myview' && $display_id == 'page_1') {
    $current_time = date('H'); //24hrs format
    if ($current_time >= 8 && $current_time <= 20) {
      $args[] = "value of day radio button";
    }
    else {
      $args[] = "value of night radio button";
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Just to be clear, **do not** use the PHP code in a contextual filter. Modify the contextual filter argument through a hook.

Comment: Okay..That's a good approach..
you can use hook_views_query_alter() hook. and set where clause for that field. by calculating above code. Let me alter my previous comment.

Comment: While I haven't tested it, I was always under the impression the `hook_views_query_alter` was very heavy. I personally use `hook_views_pre_view` to change the args of a view, although I am sure there are at least a couple other options. Please correct me if my assumption is incorrect.

Comment: Ya..right you can use `hook_views_pre_view` hook for this..there are other hooks which can be used..such as `hook_views_query_alter`.
But for this case you can use `hook_views_pre_view`

Comment: I have tried the code below:

`function hook_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if ($view->name == 'home_featured_content' && $display_id == 'panel_pane_1') {
$current_time = date('H'); //24hrs format
if ($current_time >= 8 && $current_time <= 20) {
  $args[] = "1";
}else {
  $args[] = "0";
  }
 }
}`

When I try to preview with "1" value as contextual filter, it shows me Day Content, but when I try "0", no result returns. And if I try "Night" as contextual filter, it shows me Night Content. How should I change the code?

Comment: Try setting different values for radio inputs for day and night values.
and use those values in code in `if ($current_time >= 8 && $current_time <= 20) {
  $args[] = "value of day radio button";
}else {
  $args[] = "value of night radio button";
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea.

First off however, I think you should use a date(time) field instead of the boolean. You can then use the between operators for your filter. I haven't used the date field as a contextual filter though so I will double check that in a few.

The other option, if necessary, would be to do your check on `time()` in a `hook_views_pre_view` and change your `$view-args` to the corresponding boolean (make sure to change the right element of the array if you have multiple contextual filters).

I would only use the second option if the date contextual filter is not an option for you.